# Scroll in a page of a nativescript-vue app

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript-vue

I have a template component like that (page):

```
<template>
 <Page class="page" v-if="showDisplay">
  <ActionBar class="action-bar" title="Resultsiiii"/>
  <StackLayout v-if="posts">
    <Label :text="code"></Label>
    <Label v-if="posts.product_name" :text="posts.product_name" />
    <Image :src="posts.image_thumb_url" stretch="none" />
    <Label :text="posts.ingredients_text_fr" class="list-group-item-text" textWrap="true"></Label>
   <Label :text="ingredientsList[0]"></Label>
    <StackLayout backgroundColor="#3c495e">
      <Label v-for="(item, i) in ingredientsList" :key="i" :text="item" height="70" backgroundColor="#43b883"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout v-else>
      <Label text="No infos about this product"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </Page>
</template>
```

In my loop over ingredientsList i have a problem only the ten first are showing and i can't scroll down to see others. Is there a way to get a scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

Oups (rtfm) in fact there is a scrollview element just done for this purpose : https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/scroll-view/